# VS Code Syntax TypeScript Syntax Highlighting

Tags: macos, typescript, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code

I've recently started coding TypeScript in VS Code, but I did thought that the syntax highlighting is really bad. So I started to Google around and found out that at its best it could look like this:

[image]

Mine looks like this:

[image]

I am using TypeScript 2.0.3 and working on a mac 10.11.6.

Answer (score 73):

What helped me was what @Reg1nleifr mentioned in their comment: Switching the color scheme.

Go to **Preferences -> Color Theme** and change it to **Dark+ (default dark)**.

Comment: Perfect, without installing any other extensions !

Comment: After the most recent VS code update introduced the "Dark Modern" theme as default, I'm sure a lot of people will have attempted to change back to their old theme and accidently selected the similar at first glance "Dark (Visual Studio)" theme. This is the mistake I made.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting in VSCode is driven by textmate files. This is the repository : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-TmLanguage/

It recently (16 days ago) went through a massive refactor : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-TmLanguage/pull/257 so hopefully it should get better if you update to vscode latest.

## More

The best highlighting would come if it was done using the same code the compiler uses to *parse* the code. That isn't how vscode is architectured at the moment, so I do have my own code that does it : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/alm/content/features/typescript.html#syntax-highlighting

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate the help. 
But I already had the lastest version of vscode installed (Sorry for not mentioning it already).
Howerver I found out a trick in code to achieve what i wanted: I went to **Preferences -> Color Theme -> Dark (Visual Studio)** and changed it to **dark+ (default dark)**