# Cannot get any highlighting or linting in VSCode (Espeically TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, text-editor

I looked at these questions as well without any luck:

- [VS Code Syntax TypeScript Syntax Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822230/vs-code-syntax-typscript-syntax-highlighting)
- Many YouTube videos (just made me install useless extentions)

In addition I even setup a new project and configured ES Lint. I did:

- `yarn init`
- `yarn add -D @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`
- Created a `tsconfig.json` with:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
  },
  "files": ["*.ts/*.tsx"]
}
```

And then creating `test.ts`. I expect it to behave like this: 
[image]

This is what it gives me: (absolultely frickin' nothing. No autocomplete. No autosuggestion. No linting or tooltip). 
[image]

I believe there is something fundamentally wrong with my VSCode, that uninstalling, reinstalling and removing all extensions couldn't solve.

Comment: Did you disable the built-in `JavaScript and TypeScript language features` extension? Search `@builtin` in the extensions view to check

Comment: It looks like the ony Language feature here is os CSS, C/C++ and C#.