# Typescript Semantic Highlighting not working (at all)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Just open my vscode today and found vscode syntax highlighting for typescript does not work. Unlike [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822230/vs-code-syntax-typescript-syntax-highlighting), mine doesn't work, at all. This is what it's look like:

[image]

I've tried downgrading my vscode version from 1.73 to 1.70, but it doesn't work. Quite suspicious because of the typescript and night-owl theme, because the night-owl theme work for other programming languages, and the typescript **doesn't work with any** theme at all.

Comment: Me too... I'm using the `Atom One Dark` theme with the same problem

Comment: have you tried restarting the ts server from the command pallette?

Comment: @nullptr Already try it, still doesn't work. Found a reference for that at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64456017/14320451).

Answer (score 0):

Found that the problem has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74470708/14320451), just gonna leave this question here, and make this duplicate.