# Visual Studio Code syntax highlighting is not working for JavaScript and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

This suddenly happened after I created a new file while working on a project. Almost all characters are simply white text (except for brackets, because I have *bracket pair colorization* enabled)

[image: First image showing how JavaScript and TypeScript syntax highlighting is not working]

[image: second image showing how JavaScript and TypeScript syntax highlighting is not working]

[image: third image showing how JavaScript and TypeScript syntax highlighting is not working]

I already tried resetting my configurations, checked my configurations (both globally and in my workspace), and tried [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=evgeniypeshkov.syntax-highlighter) that offers an alternative syntax highlighting (which worked, but I would prefer using the Visual Studio Code one).

Comment: Many related issues have been raised in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-typescript-next/issues

Comment: Why does everybody insist on misspelling [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript)? Can it be blamed on autocorrect?

Comment: Disabled _all_ extensions, removed _all_ user settings. Still the JS inside my .html files sometimes loses its syntax coloring randomly inside the code. When first loading the file it is correctly and then after one second, it flashes back to wrong coloring. I've reported this [here on GitHub as an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/205942). Hope the tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

I think this was caused by the extension called JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly. This was causing the syntax highlighting for *.js* and *.ts* files (*.jsx* and *.tsx* too). This was more of a bug with the latest version (currently 1.73.1).

You can disable the extension to enable the syntax highlighting.

[image: JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly]

---

This extension has now been updated and this issue is fixed.

Comment: I already two time reinstall the vocode before found this issue.. So funny

Comment: I have the same question today, it spent a lot of time. fix it when uninstall the extension.

Comment: I'm loving you! Just to know: how did you came to this? I would be interested in listeing the process which made you come to this conclusion. Thanks dude!

Comment: Previously, I had experienced this issue with CSS after installing POSTCss extension. I looked if this only happens with a specific language. Then I found out it was related to a language extension or so. So, I looked up in all of the extensions I had related to JS. I experimented by disabling one by one and I found out this extension was disabling it. That's the process of taking to the solution. Thanks for all the love, Haneen <3!

Comment: You can just downgrade the version instead of disabling it

Comment: There is already an update to fix this issue, you don't have to disable that extension. Though I probably gonna disable that for some time, cause this bug cost me a day.

Comment: Could continue to work with the colors all messed up, but threw me a bit. Weird what colors can do.

Answer (score 33):

What [user Haneen said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470708/visual-studio-code-syntax-highlighting-is-not-working-for-javascript-and-typescr/74470833#74470833) was correct, but instead of disabling it, you can install an old version that works just fine.

Click the cog on the bottom right → *'Install Another Version'* → select an older version.

[Cog at bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnFR5.png)

Comment: Note that on my vscode, the option to install another version was on the 'uninstall' button dropdown menu.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, this is exactly caused by the *JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly* extension.

You can disable or install another version (I recommend installing the prior version since the current version has a bug).

[image]

I am currently using the version which was released 2022-11-13.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had to remove `"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark"`
from settings panel.

As for your settings, you can open your them through the command palette:

- Press <kbd>F1</kbd>
- Type **user settings**
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Click the "sheet" icon to open the `settings.json` file:
  [image: settings icon]
- Remove `workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",`

if you don't have these lines, then just remove all lines it should work.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

The current version (*v5.0.20221116*) for **JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly** seems to be breaking the syntax highlighting. Downgrading to a previous version might resolve this issue.

[image]

This was resolved in *v5.0.20221117* however.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I deleted this **JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly** package, and now it works fine for me.

The module on the marketplace: *[JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next)*

Answer (score -1):

As others mentioned, the two latest versions are causing issue for me, but [5.20221115](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPEsk.png) is working for me.

Answer (score -2):

It was fixed with the latest update of *`JavaScript` and `TypeScript` Nightly*.

Comment: works with v5.0.202211170