# the text is all white in babel/js and react. What can I do to change it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx, prettier

[image]
Text is all white here. I do nothing yesterday everything was okay. Can someone help?

Comment: What extensions have you installed at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to fix it by disabling/uninstalling the `vscode-babel-coloring` plugin for Babel ES6/7 syntax coloring by `dzannotti`.

OR you can try to install this plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel

Comment: I am on Mac so don't have that dir

Comment: I have updated the answer you can try some other approaches @dadu

Comment: Can you click the extensions tab and let me know what kind of plugins you are using now? @dadu

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the extension called Javascript and Typescript Nightly.
As for a temporary fix, you could downgrade or either disable it.

See [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470708/vscode-syntax-highlighting-not-working-for-javascript-typescript/74470833#74470833)

Answer (score 0):

It's set as plain text as you can see in the bottom right corner. You have to save it as one of VS Code's given file extensions or you have to download a extensions for your programming language.

Ref: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470708/visual-studio-code-syntax-highlighting-is-not-working-for-javascript-and-typescr/74470833#74470833)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guidline to improve your contribution. Please do not link to a solution as the link may be dead in a while.