# Text is white in vscode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Anyone can help me fix this? I'm using one time pad theme but it looks like this, every code in js or ts has white text but it is normal in other code

[image]

I have tried other themes but it always show me like that, text color of js and ts doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the VSCode's Javascript and Typescript Nightly extension. You can either disable it or downgrade it to fix this issue.

[Reference to the original discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470708/vscode-syntax-highlighting-not-working-for-javascript-typescript/74470833#74470833)

Comment: Omg thank you so much! problem is fixed.