# No coloring of typescript keywords in vscode after vscode update

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, colors, keyword

After an update today, my code is no longer colored as shown below
[image]

For example, the keyword "import" is not coloured.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VsCode Syntax Highlighting not working for javascript/typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470708/vscode-syntax-highlighting-not-working-for-javascript-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by disabling "JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly" extension