# vscode's theme is not colorizing the letters

Tags: visual-studio-code

Yesterday my vscode was working perfectly, but I dawned today and for some reason it seems that the theme is not working anymore. The editor identifies the language of the file but doesn't colorize the letters the right way, leaving almost everything white.
NOTE: html, .env and json files are working fine, but .ts files are not. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VsCode Syntax Highlighting not working for javascript/typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470708/vscode-syntax-highlighting-not-working-for-javascript-typescript)

Comment: Resolved! Thanks Timothy G.