# Color and Highlighting Syntax removed from Javascript/Typesript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]

I was coding. But color division about the code disappeared. I can't understand why every code changed all white color.
In this condition, remark doesn't work and I can't do a lot of things.
I hope I can get the answer here.
Thank you for reading.

I reinstalled `VScode`, but it doesn't work

I hope color division of the code works.

Comment: I had the same exact problem, see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470708/vscode-syntax-highlighting-not-working-for-javascript-typescript

Comment: first looking through the questions with the same tag might help, you are number >5 asking the same question today

Comment: Thank you ! i solved the problem. even  i didn't know how to search this problemm (i didn't know this issue's name). thank you !