# why did the text in my vs code turn white?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, restart, color-scheme

Okay so my vs code was normal, then i restarted my laptop without closing the app. I opened it after and almost all the text was white. It isnt the theme, because its always been on Dark+. I dont think i clicked anything major that would cause this. Its really hard to code like this. It is  javascript file btw.

This is a screenshot of what it looks like:
[image]

As you can see, the comments that are meant to be green are white, the file imports and text that are meant to be orange are white. 'await' that is meant to be purple is white. even 'const' is white. anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS-Code?

Comment: have you read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes ?

Comment: VS (not code) had this problem occasionally - something to do with the language service for javascript.    There might be similar options in VS Code:  Options: Text Editor / JavaScript / Language Servce  (I don't use VS code, so just a suggestion)

Comment: @freedomn-m I too suspected it, but the status line shows "javascript"

Comment: first looking through the questions with the same tag might help, you are number 5 asking the same question today

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VsCode Syntax Highlighting not working for javascript/typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470708/vscode-syntax-highlighting-not-working-for-javascript-typescript)

Answer (score 4):

The theme thats currently active on the screenshot is Dark, what you want is Dark+.

Check if you have set your color-theme to Dark+ by going to View > Command Pallete > "Preference: Color Theme". It seems to be set to Dark, then set it to Dark+.

Comment: no its on Dark+. thats why i know it isnt a theme problem

Comment: Then I don't know what happened to you vs-code. I can tell that the white text is the same as in the basic Dark theme. Maybe try setting it to Light/Dark and then back to Dark+ to update VSCode's settings.json file will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I opened my vscode today.
Disabling the Javascript and Typescript Nightly extension fixed my issue.

Comment: how do i do that please

Comment: @gerard [linked duplicate will tell you how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470708/vscode-syntax-highlighting-not-working-for-javascript-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and I've fixed it by disabling **JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly** extension

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).